# Memory usage in dart lists

Tags: list, dart, pointers, memory

I've recently learned that lists in Dart will work like pointers such that

```
final List<int> a = [1,2,3,4]
final List<int> b = a;

b[1] = 5;

print(a);
print(b);
```

Will output the following

```
[1,5,3,4]
[1,5,3,4]
```

If you had a bit of code where

```
List<int> a = [1,2,3,4];
final List<int> b = List.from(A);

a = b;
```

Would you have stranded the memory at the address `a` was originally assigned to, or would Dart know to delete this, when `b` is pointed to the memory address of `b`?

Comment: A brief explanation from the dart website: [Dart is a garbage-collected language, which means that any Dart object that isn’t referenced can be disposed by the garbage collector.](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#weak-references-and-finalizers) When you do `A = B`, the original list object `[1,2,3,4]` is no longer referenced by anything and therefore can be disposed by the garbage collector.

Comment: Please use proper capitalization for variable names (and everything!).